# How do I create a dataset in VB.NET from this code?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, oledb

I currently have the following code in my project which populates a DataGridView object with the results of an SQL query.

```
Sub PerformQuery(ByVal SQLText As String)
    Dim DbConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(createConnectionString)

    Dim SQLQuery As String = SQLText

    Dim Adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery, DbConnection)

    Try
        Using Table As New DataTable
            Adapter.Fill(Table)
            Table.Locale = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            DbConnection.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Elsewhere in my project I can create a `DataSet` object using the code

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
```

And then extract data from it using code like:

```
MaxRows = ds.Tables("Dataset_Users").Rows.Count
```

Rather than populating a DataGridView, how can I use the `PerformQuery` code to create a dataset?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Create and fill a dataset instead of a datatable.  You dont need a DataSet though to get the rows count - they are mostly just a tables collection.  You probably want to make a form level object though if you want to use it elsewhere - but you could do the samething with your table if you didnt dipose of it

Comment: `MaxRows = ds.Tables("Dataset_Users").Rows.Count`  Note that a DataSet does not hold any data.  It holds 1 or more tables: notice how that code drills into the collection to act on a specific table.  you could also get it when you create the table: `MaxRows = Adapter.Fill(Table)`

Comment: The `PerformQuery()` method is deeply flawed because it forces you to write code that will be crazy vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You need to add an additional parameter to the method to accept query data in addition to the query text and then further update the method to use that data to create parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after the following:

```
Try
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Using Table As New DataTable
        Adapter.Fill(Table)
        Table.Locale = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        DbConnection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
        ds.Table.Add(Table)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Or as in your example you was after the Number of rows in the dataset you can do the same with the DataTable, For Example:

```
Try
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Using Table As New DataTable
        Adapter.Fill(Table)
        Table.Locale = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        DbConnection.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Table

        '' Getting the number of rows in the DataTable
        MaxRows = Table.Rows.Count
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Think in a more functional style. *Return* the table instead of setting to grid. While we're here, let's update the method so you don't have to write queries anymore that leave you wide open to sql injection attacks:

```
Function PerformQuery(ByVal SQLText As String, ByVal ParamArray Parameters() As OleDbParameter) As DataTable
    Dim result As New DataTable()

    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(createConnectionString), _
          cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLText, cn), _
          Adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, cn)

        If Parameters IsNot Nothing AndAlso Parameters.Length > 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters)
        End If
        Adapter.Fill(result)
    End Using

    Return Result
End Function
```

Note that I also removed the error handling and locale code. You still need to do that stuff, but when you want to just return a datatable instead of interact directly with the user interface in a method you have effectively moved your code to a lower level of abstraction. When you do that, you probably don't want to deal with the error handling at this lower level any more; instead let the exceptions bubble up where you can handle them closer to the user interface.

Now you call the updated method like this:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?"
Dim CustID As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("CustomerId", OleDbType.Integer)
CustID.Value = 123456

Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = PerformQuery(sql, CustID)
Catch Ex As Excpetion
    MsgBox(Ex.Message)
End Try
```